# In hive how to convert the date to MM/DD/YY format

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, datetime-format

I have created a table and loaded the data, data looks like this

```
1904287  Christopher Rodriguez Jan 11, 2003
963915   Thomas Stewart        6/17/1969
2236067  John Nelson           08/22/54
```

for the last column, date formats are different.Currently its a `string` data type in hive.

I need to change the all values from third column to required format like `MM/DD/YY` format in hive table.

Comment: @ravi- were you get the answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your third date seems invalid to me, it can have multiple combination of years.

```
CREATE TABLE test_dev_db.datetable
(Id string,
 Name string,
 user_date string
 )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS orc
;

INSERT INTO TABLE test_dev_db.datetable VALUES
('1904287', 'Christopher Rodriguez', 'Jan 11, 2003'),
('963915', 'Thomas Stewart', '6/17/1969'),
('2236067', 'John Nelson', '08/22/54');

 set hive.cli.print.header=true;

select Id,Name,user_date,
CASE WHEN user_date rlike '[a-zA-Z]{3} [0-9]{2}, [0-9]{4}' 
THEN 
to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(user_date,'MMM dd,yyyy'))) 
WHEN user_date rlike '[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'
THEN 
to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(user_date,'MM/dd/yyyy'))) 
WHEN user_date rlike '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}'
THEN 
to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('08/22/54','MM/dd/yyyy')))
end as format_date
from test_dev_db.datetable;

id      name                    user_date       format_date
1904287 Christopher Rodriguez   Jan 11, 2003    2003-01-11
963915  Thomas Stewart          6/17/1969       1969-06-17
2236067 John Nelson             08/22/54        0054-08-22
Time taken: 0.467 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```